# Child Routing Angular2 not working without useAsDefault: true

Tags: angular

In my below angular2 routing program, routing is not working if i remove useAsDefault: true and getting the below error.

> EXCEPTION: Link "["Pen"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction.
>   in [['Pen'] in AppComponent@4:19]

`**This is Child routing Code:**`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {RouteParams} from "angular2/router";
import {Pen1Component} from "./pen/app.component.pen1";
import {Pen2Component} from "./pen/app.component.pen2";


@Component({
    templateUrl:'dev/products/app.component.pen.html'
    template: `
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Pen1']">Pen1</a></li>

                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Pen2']">Pen2</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    })
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Pen1', component: Pen1Component},
    {path: '/pen2', name: 'Pen2', component: Pen2Component}

export class PenComponent {
}
```

**This is parent routing code:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {PenComponent} from './products/app.component.pen';
import {BookComponent} from './products/app.component.book';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Pen']">Pen</a></li>

                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Book',{id:1}]">Book</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]

})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/pen/...', name: 'Pen', component: PenComponent},
    {path: '/book/:id', name: 'Book', component: BookComponent}


])


export class AppComponent {

}
```

But If add this code, its working fine.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Pen1', component: Pen1Component, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/pen2', name: 'Pen2', component: Pen2Component}
```

Comment: Not sure if it works without useAsDefault option unless you use a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code in app.component.ts.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {PenComponent} from './products/app.component.pen';
import {BookComponent} from './products/app.component.book';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Penn']">Pen</a></li>

                <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Book',{id:1}]">Book</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]

})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/penn/', name: 'Penn', component: PenComponent},
    {path: '/book/:id', name: 'Book', component: BookComponent}

])


export class AppComponent {

}
```

I replace the `Pen` with `Penn`.

> You can run Angular2 without `useAsDefault: true`. This will not
>   return any error, output will be none in this case.

Comment: There is some reserved words for AngularJs. May **Pen** is a word like that. I am not sure about this, I just try with some other name and its worked.

Comment: No its not working. But If I add this code its working fine.                                  @RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Pen1', component: Pen1Component, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/pen2', name: 'Pen2', component: Pen2Component}

Comment: what is your issue now? did you try with different names?